# xamarin forms - bind TapGestureRecognizer to code-behind rather than view model

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I realise this breaks the MVVM pattern, but is it possible to bind a TapGestureRecognizer to a method in the XAML.cs code behind rather than the view model?

```
  <Image.GestureRecognizers>
      <TapGestureRecognizer 
        Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.SetImageCommand, Source={x:Reference ThePage}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
  </Image.GestureRecognizers>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just use the `Tapped` event.

```
<TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Thing_Tapped" />
```

and in your code-behind:

```
public void Thing_Tapped (object sender, EventArgs args)
{
   // Do your thing
}
```

Maybe, on second glance, you mean if you can *bind* the `Command` to something in the code-behind. I haven't tested it, but it looks it should work with your code and a minor adjustment, just do this:

```
<Image.GestureRecognizers>
      <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=SetImageCommand, Source={x:Reference ThePage}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
</Image.GestureRecognizers>
```

Notice how I removed `BindingContext.` from the binding. This means it was binding to the `BindingContext` property of your page. You can of course bind to other properties as well. You can now simply move your `SetImageCommand` to the code-behind of your page and it should work.

Either way, you can now trigger logic from your page instead of your view model.

Comment: Added a bit more in case you still wanted to use the command :-) and thanks!

Comment: one more thing if you don't mind? If I did go with the Tapped option, can I pass the tapped object as a parameter to the called code?

Comment: Not very easily. The `sender` parameter should be the `TapGestureRecognizer`. So you could do something like: `((TapGestureRecognizer)sender).CommandParameter`, given that you still put the value in the `CommandParameter` property.